# The item $/MyTeamProject/Main already exists

Tags: tfs

So I have been messing around creating and deleting (read destroying via TfsDeleteProject) in preparation for something I have to do in production soon.

When I try to recreate the sample team project with the same name I have no problem but when I try to re-create the same structure (i.e. creating the Main folder) I get the error in the title of this post:

```
"The item $/MyTeamProject/Main already exists."
```

I have tried deleting the team project, clearing my local tfs cache and reopening VS but each time when I try to create the Main folder I get the error.

So something is not getting deleted. Any ideas?

EDIT: I wanted to point out as well that I have removed the physical folders on my local system as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly intuitive because I clearedmy local tfs cache (multiple times) BUT...

After my latest repeat of the steps above (definition of insanity) I decided to do a Get Latest on the team project.

I was then able to re-create the Main folder.

Comment: I found I had to check in my delete for it to properly disappear on 2012.

Comment: I agree with Ben. You have to check-in the changes before TFS will properly recognise them (currently using Visual Studio Online - TFS 2013).

Comment: Everything was checked in